How to Create a Generic Transformer Function for Subtypes in TypeScript (without type assertions)?
I am working on a personal project to learn functional programming with TypeScript and am experimenting with the pipe function and higher-order functions to create transformers in an expressive way. I ran into some issues with TypeScript typing, especially when trying to create a generic function that returns a transformer of some object of one type into a subtype of that object.
Here is the setup:
type Cat = {
  whiskers: number;
}

type FancyCat = Cat & {
  tophatSize: number;
}

type PartyCat = Cat & {
  balloons: number;
}

I want to create a function that generically creates a transformer to update any property on any object, transforming an object into a subtype of that object (adding properties).
I can do this with a hardcoded function:
const createFancyCatTransformer = (props: { tophatSize: number }) => (cat: Cat) => {
  return {
    ...cat,
    ...props
  }
}

const cat = {
  whiskers: 50
}

const fancyCat = pipe(cat, createFancyCatTransformer({ tophatSize: 5 }));

However, I would like to make this generic. Instead of createFancyCatTransformer, I want a generic function like createTransformerToSubtype<Cat, FancyCat>({ tophatSize: 5 }).
I couldn't get this working, so to simplify further I decided to try to make a transformer to generically extend Cat to one of its subtypes, but I had issues with this as well.
Here’s my attempt at making a generic transformer for Cat:
const createCatExtender =
  <E extends Cat>(extension: Omit<E, keyof Cat>) =>
  (originalObject: Cat): E => {
    return { ...originalObject, ...extension };
  };

// Usage
createCatExtender<PartyCat>({ balloons: 7 });

However, I get the following TypeScript error:
Type '{ whiskers: number; } & Omit<E, "whiskers">' is not assignable to type 'E'.
  '{ whiskers: number; } & Omit<E, "whiskers">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'E', but 'E' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Cat'

It goes without saying, I don't want to use any type assertions or anything like that. My example works if I assert "as E" in the return statement, but I want to avoid that.
Is it possible to create a generic version of this function without TypeScript errors? How can I create a transformer that generically updates a property on any object type?

I think you've run into the issue of TS not having negative types. I.e. TS has no concept that Omit<E, keyof Cat> is Cat minus Extension, and can only evaluate Omit<E, keyof Cat> as {} and check that Cat & {} is Cat (the constraint), but can't take the logic further. I would suggest casting. An alternative is to return Cat & Omit<E, keyof Cat> which is structurally identical and wrap it in Expand<>/Prettify<> to make it readable.

I agree with prev comment; is there a reason why you need TS to believe that it's returning an E instead of Cat & Omit<E, keyof Cat>? After all, it really isn't true; you could have interface WhiskerlessCat extends Cat { whiskers: 0 } and then your code claims to return a WhiskerlessCat which might not be. An assertion lets you admit that what you're doing is technically unsafe. See this playground link. Please [edit] to make it clear what you expect when E has overlapping properties with Cat, and let me know if we've fully addressed the question yet.

You could use two generics (B for base and E for extension) and the utility RemoveProperties:
type Cat = {
  whiskers: number;
}

type FancyCat = Cat & {
  tophatSize: number;
}

type PartyCat = Cat & {
  balloons: number;
}

type RemoveProperties<T, U> = Omit<T, keyof U>;

const createTransformer = <
B extends {},
E extends B>(extension: RemoveProperties<E, B>
) => {
  return (base: B) => {
    return { ...base, ...extension } as E;
    // as E is optional but it will be cleaner than B & RemoveProperties<E, B>
  }
}

Then you can consume it like this:
const fancyCatTransformer = createTransformer<Cat, FancyCat>({ tophatSize: 3 });
const partyCatTransformer = createTransformer<Cat, PartyCat>({ balloons: 7 });

const baseCat = { whiskers: 3 };

const fancyCat = fancyCatTransformer(baseCat);

console.log(
  fancyCat.tophatSize, // OK
  fancyCat.whiskers, // OK
  fancyCat.balloons // Error
);

const partyCat = partyCatTransformer(baseCat);

console.log(
  partyCat.tophatSize, // Error
  partyCat.whiskers, // OK
  partyCat.balloons // OK
);

The createTransformer function is generic so that you can use it with Cat or something else.
Bonus
This might not be what you want, but if you replace extends B with extends {} remove the as E
const createTransformer = <
B extends {},
E extends {}>(extension: RemoveProperties<E, B> // <-- HERE (change extends B)
) => {
  return (base: B) => {
    return { ...base, ...extension }; // <-- HERE (remove as E)
  }
}

Then you will be able to do this as well:
const fancyPartyCatTransformer = createTransformer<
  FancyCat,
  PartyCat
>({ balloons: 7 });

const fancyPartyCat = fancyPartyCatTransformer(fancyCat);

console.log(
  fancyPartyCat.tophatSize, // OK
  fancyPartyCat.whiskers, // OK
  fancyPartyCat.balloons // OK
);

